Run external exe and show output with a class
I found this class on GT Hub. This is the complete code:
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class ProcessAsyncHelperClass
{
    public static async Task<ProcessResult> RunProcessAsync(string command, string arguments, int timeout)
    {
        //var result = new ProcessResult();
        ProcessResult result = new ProcessResult();

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var outputCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    outputCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
                }
            };

            var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var errorCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    errorCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorBuilder.Append(e.Data);
                }
            };

            var isStarted = process.Start();
            if (!isStarted)
            {
                result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
                return result;
            }

            // Reads the output stream first and then waits because deadlocks are possible
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            // Creates task to wait for process exit using timeout
            var waitForExit = WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);

            // Create task to wait for process exit and closing all output streams
            var processTask = Task.WhenAll(waitForExit, outputCloseEvent.Task, errorCloseEvent.Task);

            // Waits process completion and then checks it was not completed by timeout
            if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), processTask) == processTask && waitForExit.Result)
            {
                result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
                result.Output = outputBuilder.ToString();
                result.Error = errorBuilder.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // Kill hung process
                    process.Kill();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(Process process, int timeout)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit(timeout));
    }


    public class ProcessResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Exit code
        /// <para>If NULL, process exited due to timeout</para>
        /// </summary>
        public int? ExitCode { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Standard error stream
        /// </summary>
        public string Error { get; set; } = "";

        /// <summary>
        /// Standard output stream
        /// </summary>
        public string Output { get; set; } = "";
    }

}

Inside Form1 I instantiate the class and I use the following code:
private async void Test()
{
ProcessAsyncHelperClass.ProcessResult processResult = new ProcessAsyncHelperClass.ProcessResult();
processResult.Output += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandlerDownload);

var res = await ProcessAsyncHelperClass.RunProcessAsync(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\youtube-dl.exe", ArgumentsLine, 5000);

if (res.ExitCode != 0) { }
}

private void OutputHandlerDownload(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    try
    {
        if (outLine.Data.Contains("[download]") && outLine.Data.Contains("ETA"))
        {
            string output = outLine.Data.Replace("[download]  ", "Download ");
            lblProgress.Text = output.Trim();
            string stringLine = Regex.Match(outLine.Data, @"\d+\.*\d+").Value;
            string[] tokens = stringLine.Split('.');
            if (int.TryParse(tokens[0], out xj))
            {
                progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]); lblPercent.Text = tokens[0] + "%";
            }
        }
        else if (outLine.Data.Contains("Permission denied") || outLine.Data.Contains("Failed"))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}


Everything works fine, butI can't see the output messages from the youtube-dl.exe file.
Can anyone suggest me a solution or a different approach?
I use this code:
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\youtube-dl.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = ArgumentsLine;
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDir;
 process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 //* Set your output and error (asynchronous) handlers
 process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandlerMP3Download);
 process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandlerMP3Download);
 //* Start process and handlers
 process.Start();
 procID = process.Id;
 process.BeginOutputReadLine(); process.BeginErrorReadLine();
 process.WaitForExit();

The Form1 is frozen until the process is completed!
